# Jquery ui dialog close event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, dialog

I want to refresh page when close the dialog? Is this possible? How can I do this? 
There are links that opens the their own dialog. But When I clicked first time any link, dialog cache it's id, And then I clicked others, link id always same (first clicked id).

Should I refresh the page when close the dialog or Is there another way to fix this problem.

I use codes in below for opening dialog:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>@Html.ActionLink(linkText: item.musteri_adi,
           actionName: "MusteriDuzenle",
           controllerName: "Musteri",
           routeValues: new { sno = item.sno },
           htmlAttributes: new { @class = "open_dialog", data_dialog_title = item.musteri_adi })
       </td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.fatura_adresi)
       </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Thanks. And sorry my poor english :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **beforeClose** event to call a function to refresh your page.

```
$( "#myDialog" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      window.location.reload(); 
      // or you can use window.location = 'mypage.html';
}
});
```

Comment: window.location.reload(); does not work. and window.location = 'mypage.html'; is not usable for me because I use external dialog js file so each dialog's pages are different.

Comment: There must be something like this : returnUrl

Comment: you can get the current page in javascript by doing `foo = window.location.href`.